# Initialize 3d boolean array in java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

```
public Class() {
  this.bools = {{{true,false,true,true}, {true,true,false,false}, {true,false,false,true}, {true,true,false,false} },
    { {true,false,false,true}, {false,true,false,false}, {false,true,true,true}, {false,true,false,true} },
    { {false,true,true,true}, {false,true,false,true}, {true,false,false,true}, {false,true,false,false} },
    { {true,false,true,true}, {true,false,true,false}, {false,true,true,false}, {false,true,true,true} }
  };
}
```

When this code is run i get 3 errors multiple times,

- error: not a statement
- error: ';' expected
- error illegal start of expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `this.bools = ...` is not a declaration.  That is what is causing the syntax error messages.

At the top level of a Java class, the only things that are allowed are:

- Field declarations
- Method declarations
- Constructor declarations
- Nested class and interface declarations
- Static and instance initializer blocks (obscure!)

But `this.bools = ...` is an assignment statement, not a declaration.

If you want to declare `bools` as a field of the class, you need a field declaration.  It would look like this:

```
private boolean[][][] bools = ...
```

The `private` is the visibility modifier for the field.  (It could be `public` or `protected` ... or omitted entirely.

The `boolean[][][]` is the type specifier for the declaration.  In this case it is and "array of array of array of boolean"; i.e. a 3-D array of `boolean` values.

(I have left out the stuff after the `=` because what you have looks correct.)

Answer (score 3):

Your array syntax is fine, but you seem to have some broken class definition.  Consider this working version:

```java
public class YourClass {
    private boolean[][][] bools = {
        { {true,false,true,true}, {true,true,false,false}, {true,false,false,true}, {true,true,false,false} },
        { {true,false,false,true}, {false,true,false,false}, {false,true,true,true}, {false,true,false,true} },
        { {false,true,true,true}, {false,true,false,true}, {true,false,false,true}, {false,true,false,false} },
        { {true,false,true,true}, {true,false,true,false}, {false,true,true,false}, {false,true,true,true} }
    };
}
```